# how to make LXDE hibernate the computer when the power button is being pressed

Tags: linux, power-management, hibernate, lxde

How to setup LXDE (a linux desktop environment) to hibernate a PC after the power button on the computer is pressed?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that without LXDE (or any other) GUI support. Just run acpid, it does that by default. At least on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to this on the [AskUbuntu StackExchange](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86376/how-to-specify-power-button-to-do-a-shutdown-h-now-instead-of-graphical-shutd):

When you press the power button a ACPI event triggers the script at /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh.

You can edit that to just run shutdown -h now as the first thing so it looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
# /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh
# Initiates a shutdown when the power putton has been
# pressed.

/sbin/shutdown -h now "Power button pressed"
exit 0
# leave the old code below (in case you want to revert!)
```